# Use of Boolean logic to check 2 EditText fields to provide 1 button enable or disable

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an issue where I am trying to create an app where a bill is split amongst a number of people. That being said  I must also say that I am a total beginner and the code I have written may need tightening up.
I have utilized the TextWatcher method for the watching of the two (2) EditText fields. This seems to only work in one direction where for the two (2) fields Billtotal and Number of People. The logic only seems to work in one direction where the Billtotal needs to be last for this to work. If I select the Billtotal field first to enter into the logic does not seems to work. I find this strange as I use the && operator in the Boolean logic:

```
    private void enablecalifready() {
    boolean isready= (numofpep.getText().length() > 0) && (billtotal.getText().length() > 0);
    if(isready){
            calcbtn.setEnabled(true);
    }else {
            calcbtn.setEnabled(false);
          }
    }
```

The above code is selected from the following piece of code:

```
    billtotal.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    enablecalifready();
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
}
    });
```

now my app starts with the button disabled and what I would like is when the logic finds that both the fields are populated with items no matter what the order they are entered that the button is enabled once both fields are populated.

I am open to any logic as I am new to the Android coding world and is willing to accept any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only adding the listener to the billTotal EditText so your method will only be called after you've editing the text in that field.  You should put the watcher code into a new variable and assign it as the text change listener for both EditText fields like so:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        enablecalifready();
    }

    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {  }
    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {  }
}

numofpep.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
billtotal.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Also think about approaching enabling the button the way Robin says as they are right - it is cleaner

Comment: SDJMcHattie it worked out thanks for pointing out that I did not put a listener to the number of people. I have used that with Robin's functions testing for the Boolean and your global TextWatcher. How do I state that both answers pointed me to the final answer.

Comment: I guess it depends on which you thought helped you most.  You can obviously up vote both with the arrows on the left of the answer, but you can only accept one answer.

Comment: I wish there was a way to combine both. That makes sense. The issues is that due to my newness at this, I am not at the points level to up vote as yet. This is really frustrating and bad, because you both had great input and it is a combined help that gave me the answer. I believe that you refined and pointed out the missing listener, but Robin's answer started me down that path. Ok I believe I have my answer.

Comment: thanks, I wish I had the level to up vote yours as well, as it definitely closed the door on the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    boolean isready= (numofpep.getText().length() > 0) && (billtotal.getText().length() > 0);
```

should be:

```
if(numofpep.getText().length() > 0) && (billtotal.getText().length() > 0){
    isready = true;
}else{
    isready = false;
}
```

I would use a methode for this:

```
private boolean isReady(){
    if(numofpep.getText().length() > 0) && (billtotal.getText().length() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in the afte TextChanged or the onCheckChanged methode i would do this:

```
calcbtn.setEnabled(isReady());
```

Comment: Don't return true in the first block of the `if` and return false in the `else` block.  Just return the result of the condition instead: `return (numofpep.getText().length() > 0) && (billtotal.getText().length() > 0);`

Comment: Robin I tried the suggestions above and both techniques did not work. The logic still worked like I described above. Only when I enter the number of people first does it happen. If I do it from the billtotal first it will not happen.

Comment: robin it worked SDJMcHattie pointed out that I did not put a listener to the number of people. I have used that with your functions testing for the Boolean and his global TextWatcher. How do I state that both answers pointed me to the final answer.

Comment: SDJMcHattie Is that a cleaner method of doing the code, the reason I ask is that firstly, I want to learn the best method, so that I do not acquire a lot of bad habits, secondly the code that Robin provided works as per the logic and also with your additions.

Comment: You should never have code of the form `if (someCondition) { return true; } else { return false; }`  Instead turn that into `return someCondition;` and it means exactly the same thing

Comment: SDJMcHattie I double checked the code with your suggestion and it worked, yea, thanks much for the assist. That did it, I appreciate the help.